# How to select values in drop down using selenium where values are suggested by google

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver

There is an input text area in the form. When I type the name city , it gives the suggestion of the city using google api. How can I choose my desire value?

HTML code

`<input class="focus" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter a location" name="msf-city" id="msf-city" type="text">`

[image: Google-API suggesting city name according to the enterd Text]

Comment: Can you please add the relevant HTML code snippet and the code you've worked upon ?

Comment: Also please add html snippet of any of the suggestion items that you are getting  ?

Answer (score 2):

**Below is the image related to the Google's autosuggestion search field:**
[image]

The below code will **navigate to google's site, then fill the input field with text 'stackoverflow' and then click on 'stackoverflow jobs' from the autosuggest box**:

```
//Opening browser instance
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

//Maximizing browser window
driver.manage().window().maximize();

//Implicit timeout of 10 seconds
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

//Navigate to google site
driver.get("http://google.co.in/");

//Send text to the input box
driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys("stackoverflow"); 

//Select option from the autosuggest box
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@role='listbox']//div[.='stackoverflow jobs']")).click();
```

---

From your html snippet I can only sendKeys to the textfield(like below), but not select the option from the autosuggestion box.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("msf-city")).sendKeys("some city name");
```

**So, please add the relevant HTML snippet for the options being displayed in the autosuggestion box!!**

Comment: Hi Subh, Thanks for your work.
I have attached an image for the more details. In case of more information regarding html code please let me know what exactly I need to put here.

Comment: @Nitesh: Please inspect the element **"Jabeek the Netherlands"** in the image that you've added in the question, and add the relevant HTML snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can select value from drop down as per below syntax :

```
//SELECT SPECIFIC VALUE FROM DROPDOWN

Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("your-dropdown-id")));
sel.selectByVisibleText("Value of city");

value of city : for ex : Ahmdedabad.
```

Still if you have any confusion then please share your actual html code so I can write selenium webdriver code as per your dropdown.

Comment: There is no way this is going to work for the OP, since he is obviously not dealing with a `Select` element!